# windbg dd command on hex adress giving ????question mark

Tags: windbg

what does below output in WINDBG mean,when I do dd command on hex address: a66e920

```
0:001> dd a66e920
00000000`0a66e920  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a66e930  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a66e940  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a66e950  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a66e960  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a66e970  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a66e980  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a66e990  ???????? ???????? ???????? ???????
```

Does this mean, hex adress is NULL ?
I am new to windbg:

Below is our code snippet, renamed variables,function and structure name for privacy purpose, its crashing at point while accessing hb->buck_magic, as hb is invalid.

```
`#define BUCK_MAGIC 0x4255434b  /* "BUCK"   */

typedef struct {
   Card     buck_magic;
   Card     buck_size;
   Card     buck_used;
   List_obj **  buck_list;
} Bucket;



static Bucket *bucket_get( Ptr d )
{
   Bucket *hb;
   hb = *(Bucket **)d;
   
   if ( hb->buck_magic == BUCK_MAGIC ) return(hb);
   return(0);

}`
```

---

latest frame output of crash:

```
0:001> 
00000000`012af220 char * d = 0x00000000`09630580 "???"
00000000`012af200 struct Bucket * hb = 0x00000000`0a103b80

0:001> dx -r1 ((code_bin!Bucket *)0xa103b80)
((code_bin!Bucket *)0xa103b80): 0xa103b80 [Type: Bucket *]
    [+0x000] buck_magic : Unable to read memory at Address 0xa103b80
    [+0x004] buck_size  : Unable to read memory at Address 0xa103b84
    [+0x008] buck_used  : Unable to read memory at Address 0xa103b88
    [+0x010] buck_list  : Unable to read memory at Address 0xa103b90
    
0:001> dx -r1 ((code_bin!char *)0x9630580)
((code_bin!char *)0x9630580): 0x9630580 : "???" [Type: char *]

0:001> dd 09630580
00000000`09630580  0a103b80 00000000 0a1253c0 00000000
00000000`09630590  09197bb0 00000000 06d7f980 00000000
00000000`096305a0  091afa30 00000000 091aeb30 00000000
00000000`096305b0  0a0ffbc0 00000000 091b10b0 00000000
00000000`096305c0  091a6f70 00000000 0a13bbc0 00000000
00000000`096305d0  0a13bbc0 00000000 0a17df10 00000000
00000000`096305e0  062b5570 00000000 000d760e 80000308
00000000`096305f0  00009aaf 00061aaf 00095aaf 000a9aaf
0:001> dp 09630580
00000000`09630580  00000000`0a103b80 00000000`0a1253c0
00000000`09630590  00000000`09197bb0 00000000`06d7f980
00000000`096305a0  00000000`091afa30 00000000`091aeb30
00000000`096305b0  00000000`0a0ffbc0 00000000`091b10b0
00000000`096305c0  00000000`091a6f70 00000000`0a13bbc0
00000000`096305d0  00000000`0a13bbc0 00000000`0a17df10
00000000`096305e0  00000000`062b5570 80000308`000d760e
00000000`096305f0  00061aaf`00009aaf 000a9aaf`00095aaf

0:001> dq 09630580
00000000`09630580  00000000`0a103b80 00000000`0a1253c0
00000000`09630590  00000000`09197bb0 00000000`06d7f980
00000000`096305a0  00000000`091afa30 00000000`091aeb30
00000000`096305b0  00000000`0a0ffbc0 00000000`091b10b0
00000000`096305c0  00000000`091a6f70 00000000`0a13bbc0
00000000`096305d0  00000000`0a13bbc0 00000000`0a17df10
00000000`096305e0  00000000`062b5570 80000308`000d760e
00000000`096305f0  00061aaf`00009aaf 000a9aaf`00095aaf
0:001> dp 0a103b80 
00000000`0a103b80  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103b90  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103ba0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103bb0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103bc0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103bd0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103be0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103bf0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
0:001> dq 0a103b80 
00000000`0a103b80  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103b90  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103ba0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103bb0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103bc0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103bd0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103be0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000000`0a103bf0  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
0:001> dd 0a103b80 
00000000`0a103b80  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a103b90  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a103ba0  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a103bb0  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a103bc0  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a103bd0  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a103be0  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
00000000`0a103bf0  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
```

Comment: dd is not exactly right to use in 64 bit unless you are sure of that  use dq or dp  that said the memory appears to be unavailable in you dump

Comment: @blabb: why shouldn't `dd` be ok in 64 bit? IMHO it just influences the columns in the output. `db` has single byte columns, `dd` has 4 byte columns and `dq` has 8 byte columns. Is there more than that?

Comment: @ThomasWeller dd is display dword and it can err if the address is not provided properly and as i said it is not that you cannot use it but not preferable to use it [look for dp docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/d--da--db--dc--dd--dd--df--dp--dq--du--dw--dw--dyb--dyd--display-memor)

Comment: @blabb: ok, do you mean `a66e920` could be a typo or copy/paste issue, since we would normally copy the whole pointer value from somewhere and thus make the command `dd 00000000'0a66e920`

Comment: I often see people typing those addresses, because they don't know how to copy/paste in WinDbg. When typing, they omit leading zeros. They mark a value and do a right click to get a context menu - but there is none. In fact that right click already copied the value to the clipboard.

Comment: yes and also in 32 bit context (not exactly applicable but i hope you get the point ) if this half part was 0x0`a66e920f  would fall in kernel va not user va ( i understand it is kinda nitpicking ) but i stick to using dp nowadays  and use dd only if i  am absolutely sure that ineed a 32bit value

Comment: @blabb: Apreciate your help,I have added output of dd,dp,dq by editing my question.
Also I am using proper hex adress value no miss. Any suggestion on this how can I avoid program crash in such cases.

Comment: what you edited in does not make any sense if you are live attach a debugger look at callstack and do !analyze -v if youare debugging a dump do !analyze -v to get the callstack  your argument d (why not use descriptive names ?? why code like an adolescent script kiddie )  is appears to  casted as a char * but you appear to be de referencing it as structure inside the function  that will never make sense

Comment: @ThomasWeller your edit invalidates the whole point of comment stream check  the output of dd versus dp which you edited out or dq versus dp output iwould suggest re roll the edits and emphaisize the difference

Comment: @blabb: ok, I rolled back. I didn't see any benefit, since the output of dp is identical to the one of dq. And the one of dd can easily be reconstructed from the one of dq.

Comment: to see the benefit look at the output of dd 09630580   assume you pass the first result to a subsequent dq or dp you will be looking at  0x0a103b8000000000 whereas you need to look at 0x000000000a103b80 hope i could make it clear

Comment: @blabb: it was project code snippet ,char* was type casted to structure:
   hb = *(Bucket **)d;

Answer (score 1):

The question marks indicate that the memory is not available.

For crash dumps: the memory might not be included in the crash dump, depending on the [MINIDUMP_TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/ne-minidumpapiset-minidump_type) that was used to create the crash dump. E.g. [Procdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) has an option ( `-mp`) to exclude memory regions larger than 512 MB. If you assume that's the case, create crash dumps with full memory.

For live debugging: there was never a `VirtualAlloc()` call to the operating system that returned this portion of memory. Or, the memory was allocated but has been `VirtualFree()`d, so it's no longer available. If the program would access the memory in a read or write operation, an access violation (AV) would occur.

The question marks are not equivalent to NULL values. A null pointer value at that address would be `00000000` (32 bit) or `00000000'00000000` (64 bit).

If you have a pointer that points to such memory, it might also be that you're building a C++ program in Release build, which may leave pointers with some garbage if you never initialize them ("bogus pointer"). In debug mode, they would be initialized with some memory pattern.

Side note: if you're investigating pointers, using `dp` ("dump pointer sized data") is preferred over `dd` (32 bit) or `dq` (64 bit).

Comment: Appreciate your help in this. I have edited my question where I added code snippet, and core dump latest frame output and given output of dp,dq,dd on hex adress.
Can you help me how to avoid such program crash.